# SailsJS : How to convert camel case to snake case in JSON response implicitly?

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

Is there a way in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) to convert `camelCase` to `snake_case` while returning the `JSON` response using `res.ok(data)`, where data is an object, without having explicit `getters` or `setters` in the model to do this?

Comment: What properties/values in the object do you want to convert?

Comment: I would want my attributes in my model to use camel case in nodejs and JSON API responses to be in snake cases. I would want all attributes (including user defined and auto generated attributes like createdAt and updatedAt) to follow the same?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/blakeembrey/snake-case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also another solution that don't need to be implemented in each response.

You can define your custom hook in `api/hooks` folder with following content:

```
var snakeCase = require('snake-case');

module.exports = function (sails) {
  return {
    routes: {
      after: {
        'all /*': function overrideJsonx(req, res, next) {
          var jsonx = res.jsonx;
          res.jsonx = function (obj) {
            var res = snakeCase(obj);
            jsonx(res);
          };

          next();
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It will work for all responses without modifying custom responses in `api/response` folder.